# Replace string variable inside loop

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a loop in twig/symphony, like so:

```
{% for breadcrumb in page.breadcrumbs %}    
  <a href="{{ breadcrumb.url | url }}">{{ breadcrumb.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to check the first variable in the for loop. If that equals `Artists` then the html part need to be replaced by a new piece of code.

So what I did was this:

```
 {% for breadcrumb in page.breadcrumbs %}

  {% if loop.first %}
  {% if breadcrumb.title == 'Artists' %}
  <a href="{{ 'artists' | url }}">{{ 'Artists' | t }}</a>{% else %}<a href="{{ breadcrumb.url | url }}">{{ breadcrumb.title }}</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

This works however when the bradcrumb path goes deeper then two levels then everything after the second level isn't shown anymore. So what I mean is this:

```
home > Artist > //nothing shown here anymore. Loop stops I think??

Instead of 

home > artists > category1 > subcategory 2
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong. Why does the loop stop with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop keeps going, but you've wrapped the entire output logic into the `loop.first` variable conditional.

You need to do this instead:

```
{% for breadcrumb in page.breadcrumbs %}
    {% if loop.first and breadcrumb.title == 'Artists' %}
        <a href="{{ 'artists' | url }}">{{ 'Artists' | t }}</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ breadcrumb.url | url }}">{{ breadcrumb.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way you are checking for *both* the first iteration of the loop and whether or not the title is "Artists"

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking the first iteration (first loop), and do nothing with the rest:

```
{% for breadcrumb in page.breadcrumbs %}

    {% if loop.first %}
        {% if breadcrumb.title == 'Artists' %}
            <a href="{{ 'artists' | url }}">{{ 'Artists' | t }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ breadcrumb.url | url }}">{{ breadcrumb.title }}</a>
        {% endif %}
   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I know @sjagr, I just formatted it so he could see that he was only using the first loop. He was asking "why the loop stop with this code", and I answered accordingly.